# Microsoft Graph Activites - 401 AAD Authentication Failed

Tags: api, graph, permissions

in graph explorer
the get activity method is not autorise see picture

[graph explorer get activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grrkm.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of Graph Explorer(GE), the access token GE sent to MS graph is wrong which caused this issue. Once I request the access token by myself and sent it to MS graph by postman, it work well.